# new stable web interfaces for R

Tags: r, web, interface, cloud, chromebook

Looking for a web-based R compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you can install it on your own server, *Rstudio server* seems the way to go. You will get almost the same interface as Rstudio desktop in your web browser :

http://www.rstudio.com/ide/

If you just want to develop specific web applications which execute R code, you can also take a look at Shiny :

http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/